# Allowing only a specific user to view a page

Tags: php, security, session, authorization

So I'm building a authentication system that allows clients to view work we've created for them. There is one and only one account per client. I'm trying to figure out a way to check on each page whether the person logged in is allowed to view said content.

Basically the file structure is like this: Client/Year/Project/ and then within the project folder there are folders for specific categories (flash, landing page, etc). Within each folder there is an index.php file that handles displaying the directories or projects. I need to check on each of these index pages whether the user logged in is authorized to view the page.

Currently, I have a couple session variables:

$_Session['loggedin'] - just a bool that is set to true when logged in

$_Session['client'] - this value is grabbed from the database when they log in. It's just a string of the clients full name (it's also used for displaying purposes).

As of now on each page I check to see if loggedin is set to true and I have this hard coded on each page:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['client'] != 'Clientname'){
   unset($_SESSION);
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: http://www.homepage.com");
}
```

I'm not very pleased with this solution though because I'm trying to make it as automated as possible - new clients will continue to be added and it should be possible for people to add clients without too much fuss (all of that is working fine at this point, with the exception of this)

I have to check to make sure the client is correct because the following scenario could happen otherwise: Client A logs in and the loggedin session is set to true...however, if they navigate to Client B's folder structure and it only checks to see if someone is logged in they will be able to access it.

Is there a good practice for handling something like this? I would like to implement something that can be used across all users and won't require someone to go in the code and change the client name string every time a new client is added.

Any sort of logical help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the client data in a directory outside the public visible directory structure and use mod_rewrite (if you are using Apache) to redirect all the requests to a single index.php where a FrontController will be started. This controller initializes the authentication and authorization procedure based on the request string and the session cookies.

If your document root is `/some/folder/public_html` the client data would be stored in `/some/folder/data/Client/...` and PHP will publish the content of the specific folders. You could also store the projects with their database key as folder. Then you do not need the directory structure of `Client/Year/Project/` but `some/folder/data/{project_key}/...`. With this solution the directory navigation is simpler.

Here some short excerpt of the idea:

### .htaccess

Redirect the requests with a mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/to/client/data
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA, L]
```

### index.php

This script will initialize the database connection, controller and session and process the request.

```
// initialization of database connection    
$connection = ...

// controller initialziation
$controller = new FrontController($connection, ...);

// you could encapsulate the session in its own class to make
// easy requests to the session.
$session = new Session(...);

// select the requested resource by its path
$resource = $controller->selectResourceByPath($_GET['request']);

// resouce was not found
if (!$resource) {
    $controller->showNotFound($_GET['request']);
    exit(0);
}

// validate if the session is started. If not, redirect to the login page.
if (!$session->isStarted()) {
  $controller->redirect('login');
  exit(0);
}

$user = $session->getUser();

// user is not logged in
if (!$user) {
   $controller->redirect('login');
   exit(0);
}

// this is a very simple solution. You could build up separate
// authentication/authorization layer.
if ($resource->hasAccess($user))
  $controller->showResource($resource);
else
  $controller->showAccessDenied($user, $resource);
```

Normally you would use a router and a firewall class and ACLs to protect the access for entities. Also the request processing would be structured in a router->resolver->controller chain. This is just an excerpt for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have an authentication system in place because you are setting the $current_client = $_SESSION['client'].

Also you say you have an index.php file in each client directory.

And you have the folders laid out with the client at the root. I assume the paths are:

/root/path/to/files/$$CLIENT$$/....

All you need to do is compare the current path/to/client with the $current_client.

```
// returns true if $str begins with $sub
function beginsWith( $str, $sub ) {
    return ( substr( $str, 0, strlen( $sub ) ) == $sub );
}

$authorized = beginsWith(__FILE__, '/root/path/to/files/' . $current_client) ;
```

Add that to your authorization instead of hard coding the client name.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || !$authorized){
   unset($_SESSION);
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: http://www.homepage.com");
}
```